# Unknown error in my MySQL query. Could you help me?

Tags: mysql, database

I have problems with this MySQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE profili(
    id_profilo INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_utente INT,
    id_libro INT,
    categoria VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_utente) REFERENCES utenti(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_libro) REFERENCES libri(id_libro)
        ON DELETE UPDATE
)
```

PhpMyAdmin gives me a generic "syntax error" but I don't understand

Comment: When you have an error please always provide the error message.

Comment: I updated my query but the same error appears #1064 - synthax error in SQL qury near  'UPDATE
)' line 9

Comment: *ON DELETE UPDATE* - no such option. `RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT` allowed, not `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

First to make your question more appealing to answer be so specific as possible.

Just a few things to remember

1. Always include error messages
2. Explain what you want to accomplish and why

And much more. This will increase the chance people can understand and want to help you.

The issue in this query is that the last FOREIGN KEY definition is invalid.
`ON DELETE UPDATE` is nothing and incorrect syntax.

If I execute this code I get the error:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE`

For more information about FOREIGN KEY syntax see:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html